# leaveEditMode from Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore not show toolbar

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have an extension where I set a Button to enter to edit mode from Markup extension:

```
buttonMarkup.onClick = function (e) {
    let markupExtension = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore');
    markupExtension.enterEditMode();
    toolBarMarkup.setVisible(true); // Here I set visible a custom toolbar
};
```

And I create another button in custom toolbar where I use the method leaveEditMode():

```
buttonSquare.onClick = function (e) {
    let markupExtension = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore');
    markupExtension.leaveEditMode();
}
```

[image: screenshoot]

The edit mode is out but I can't see the main toolbar again, Do I need an aditional step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
buttonSquare.onClick = function (e) {
    let markupExtension = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore');
    markupExtension.leaveEditMode();
    markupExtension.hide();
}
```

you need call: `markupExtension.hide()` to return default viewer.